# Which characters are in Broforce, and whose spoof are they?

Tags: broforce

I played the current version of Broforce, and started unlocking the characters, and I didn't find them all very obvious. Looks like I'm not that educated in action movies.

I want to know the original characters (and the films they are in) behind the characters in the game. Who are they?

Comment: Is this information stored in-game at all?

Comment: @Frank Nope, they just flash a epic action-scene title with your newly unlocked character's name across your screen on a flaming banner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the Broforce wikia](http://broforce.wikia.com/wiki/Bros), there are currently  42 Bros as of June 2017. Excluding the Expandables themed Bros mentioned [in SQB's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/295105/14775), they are:

- **Rambro** - John Rambo from the Rambo film series
- **Brommando** - John Matrix from Commando
- **B. A. Broracus** - B. A. Baracus from The A-Team TV series
- **Brodell Walker** - Cordell Walker from the Walker, Texas Ranger TV series
- **Bro Hard** - John McClane from the Die Hard film series
- **MacBrover** - Angus MacGyver from the MacGyver TV series
- **Brade** - Blade from the Blade film series
- **Bro Dredd** - Judge Dredd from Judge Dredd
- **Bro In Black** - James Edwards / Agent J from the Men In Black series
- **Snake Broskin** - Snake Plissken from Escape from New York/L.A.
- **Brominator** - The Terminator from the Terminator film series
- **Brobocop** - Alex Murphy / RoboCop from the RoboCop film series
- **Indiana Brones** - Indiana Jones from the Indiana Jones film series
- **Ash Brolliams** - Ash Williams from The Evil Dead film series
- **Mr. Anderbro** - Thomas A. Anderson / Neo from The Matrix film series
- **The Boondock Bros** - Connor and Murphy MacManus from The Boondock Saints
- **Brochete** - Machete Cortez from the Machete film series
- **Bronan the Brobarian** - Conan from the Conan The Barbarian film series
- **Ellen Ripbro** - Ellen Ripley from the Alien film series
- **Time Bro** - Max Walker from Timecop
- **Broniversal Soldier** - Luc Deveraux / GR44 from Universal Soldier
- **Colonel James Broddock** - Colonel James Braddock from Missing in Action
- **Cherry Broling** - Cherry Darling from Planet Terror
- **Bro Max** - Max Rockatansky from the Mad Max film series
- **The Brode** - Beatrix Kiddo / The Bride from the Kill Bill film series
- **Double Bro Seven** - James Bond / 007 from the James Bond film series
- **The Brodator** - A Predator from the Predator film series
- **The Brocketeer** - Cliff Secord / Rocketeer from The Rocketeer
- **Broheart** - William Wallace from Braveheart
- **The Brofessional** - Leone "Léon" Montana from The Professional
- **Broden** - Lord Raiden (film "Rayden") from Mortal Kombat (film)
- **The Brolander** - Connor MacLeod from Highlander
- **Dirty Brorry** - Inspector Harry Callahan from Dirty Harry
- **Tank Bro** - Rebecca Buck / Tank Girl from Tank Girl
- **Bro Lee** - Lee from Enter The Dragon

Answer (score 2):

### The Expendabros

All Expendabros are based on characters from *The Expendables*.

- **Broney Ross**
  Barney Ross
- **Lee Broxmas**
  Lee Christmas
- **Bronnar Jensen**
  Gunnar Jensen
- **Bro Caesar**
  Hale Caesar
- **Broctor Death**
  Doctor Death
- **Toll Broad**
  Toll Road
- **Trent Broser**
  Trench Mauser

Answer (score -3):

New ones are
Broniversal soldier-Luc Deveraux from universal soldier
Time Bro-Max Walker from Timecop
Colonel James Broddock-James Braddock from Missing in Action
And
Cherry Brolling-Cherry Darling from Planet Terror